# GWT searching node in a Tree

Tags: gwt, search

I'm stuck with a recursive searching, I'm using gwt, and basically I want to search for a node in a gwt Tree, here's my code. Thanks in advance.I'm not good at recursive :-(

```java
public TreeItem search2(String sName, TreeItem node){
    TreeItem treeItem=null;
    String sValue ="";
    boolean bFound=false;

    System.out.println("Father Node:" + node.getText() + " child nodes:" + node.getChildCount());


    for (int i=0;i<node.getChildCount();i++){

        treeItem = node.getChild(i);
        sValue = treeItem.getText();
        System.out.println("searching...."+sValue);
        if (sValue.equalsIgnoreCase(sName)){
            bFound=true;
            System.out.println("!!found!!!!"+sName + " node to return:" + treeItem.getText());
            return treeItem;
        }
        else {
            return search2(sName,treeItem);
        }
    }               

    return treeItem;

}
```

Comment: What results are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in the line `return search2(sName,treeItem);`. Only if a match was found should you return ... if no match was found then you want to continue checking the rest of the child nodes. Try this:

```
public TreeItem search2(String sName, TreeItem node) {
    if (node.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(sName) {
        return node;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TreeItem treeItem = search2(sName, node.getChild(i));
        if (treeItem != null) {
            return treeItem;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note: I edited my first answer because it would not have worked correctly if there was just one node (and the node text matched sName).

Andy